# Liberty how to specify JMS Topic in server.xml

Tags: jms, websphere-liberty

I need to send a JMS message to a topic on a IBM MQ.

How can I specify the desired topic name inside the liberty *server.xml*?

This is my current *server.xml*

```
   <jmsConnectionFactory jndiName="jms/testConnectionFactory" connectionManagerRef="testConnectionManager">
     <properties.wmqJms userName="testUser" password="testPass" transportType="CLIENT" hostName="myTestHost" port="1424" channel="SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN" queueManager="TestQManager"/>
  </jmsConnectionFactory>

  <connectionManager id="testConnectionManager" maxPoolSize="5"/>

  <jmsQueue id="jms/testQueue" jndiName="jms/testQueue">
    <properties.wmqJms baseQueueName="TEST.OUT" baseQueueManagerName="TestQManager"/>
  </jmsQueue>
```

Failed to find a snippet online which deals with topics, and I'm not interested in creating topics in code.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_msg_single_pubsub.html

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<jmsTopic id="myTopic" jndiName="jms/myTopic">
  <properties.wmqJms baseTopicName="MyTopic"/>
</jmsTopic>
```

(Edited since you already had a ConnFactory and a ConnMgr, and I didn't mean to suggest you needed to change them.)